# How to Replace Colon and Star Special Characters in JavaScript Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to replace star (*) and colon (:) with an empty string ("") and the string can be as follows:

Either: `Registration No: already exists*`

OR: `*Registration No: already exists`

So, I don't want (*) as well as (:) and output should be `Registration No already exists` how can I solve it.

Trying as follows:

```
var txt = str.replace(/:\*/ig,"");
```

Please help me and thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You regex matches `:*`. You could match either of them using a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html):

```
var txt = str.replace(/[:*]/g,"");
```

```js
const strings = [
  "Registration No: already exists*",
  "*Registration No: already exists"
];

strings.forEach((s) => {
  console.log(s.replace(/[:*]/g, ""));
});
```

Comment: You can remove the ignore case modifier since there are no lower or upper case characters in the regex.

Comment: @JohanWentholt You are right, I have removed the ignore case modifier.

Answer (score 0):

Another way without using a character class is to use a `pipe` or [alteration](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) to separate each group. This however, requires that you escape special characters and this does allow for group matches instead of single character matches:

```
var txt = str.replace(/:|\*/ig, "");
```